# Can this be simplified in a simple statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i simplify this code? Just gonna update an entire column of `Null` into names which have corresponding IDs.

```
update salesman 
set name = 'James Hoog'
where salesman_id = 5001

update salesman
set name = 'Nail Knite' 
where salesman_id = 5002

update salesman
set name = 'Pit Alex'
where Salesman_id = 5005

update salesman
set name = 'Mc Lyon' 
where salesman_id = 5006
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement to identify the `NAME` for each `salesman_id`

Try this way

```
UPDATE salesman 
SET    NAME = CASE salesman_id 
                WHEN 5001 THEN 'James Hoog' 
                WHEN 5002 THEN 'Nail Knite' 
                WHEN 5005 THEN 'Pit Alex' 
                WHEN 5006 THEN 'Mc Lyon' 
              END 
WHERE  salesman_id IN ( 5001, 5002, 5005, 5006 )
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I'm gonna add two new sets of column: New York, Paris, London, Denmark as Locations and Salary of 1500, 1300, 1200, 1100 to the given list which are 5001, 5002, 5005, 5006 respectively? How can I add them to the code in one statement and in the most simplest way?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the name and id in a different table you perform a UPDATE/JOIN

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 'James Hoog' as name, 5001 as salesman_id UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Nail Knite' as name, 5002 as salesman_id UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Pit Alex'   as name, 5005 as salesman_id UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Mc Lyon'    as name, 5006 as salesman_id 
)
UPDATE s
SET s.name = c.name
FROM salesman  s
JOIN cte c
  ON s.salesman_id = c.salesman_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a `MERGE`:

```
MERGE salesman AS t
USING (VALUES
    (5001, 'James Hoog'),
    (5002, 'Nail Knite'),
    (5005, 'Pit Alex'),
    (5006, 'Mc Lyon'))
    AS s (salesmain_id, name)
ON (t.salesman_id = s.salesman_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET name = s.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE salesman SET
      NAME = CASE WHEN salesman_id = 5001 THEN 'James Hoog' 
                  WHEN salesman_id = 5002 THEN 'Nail Knite' 
                  WHEN salesman_id = 5005 THEN 'Pit Alex' 
                  WHEN salesman_id = 5006 THEN 'Mc Lyon' END
WHERE salesman_id IN (5001,5002,5005,5006)
```

Comment: what about rows with other names?